# accessing values from a nested dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to create a list of the input with their corresponding values accessing from the global nested dictionary. Here is the code,

```
import sys

param_values = {
            'vowels':{
            'aa' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),   (-1,-1)],     
            'ae' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (0.1,0.8), (-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ah' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ao' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.2,1.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'eh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'er' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.15,0.7),  (-1,-1)], 
            'ey' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (0.3,1.0), (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.5),   (-1,-1)],
            'ih' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'iy' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (0.2,1.0), (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'uh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (0.1,1.0)], 
            'uw' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (0.1,1.0)],   
            'o'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (0.4,1.0)]    
            },
            'consonants':{
            'b'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.0,0.0),  (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ch' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'd'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'dh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.35),  (-1,-1)], 
            'dx' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.35),  (-1,-1)], 
            'f'  : [(0.3,1.0), (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (-1,-1)], 
            'g'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'hh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'jh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'k'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'l'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'm'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.0,0.0),  (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'n'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (0.3,1.0), (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ng' : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'p'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.0,0.0),  (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'r'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            's'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (0.3,1.0), (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)],
            'sh' : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (0.3,1.0), (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            't'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'th' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'v'  : [(0.3,1.0), (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (-1,-1)], 
            'w'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (0.1,1.0)], 
            'y'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.6),   (-1,-1)],  
            'z'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (0.3,1.0), (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'zh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.6),   (-1,-1)] 
             }                         
            }

diphthong = { 
         'aw' : ['ao' , 'uw'],
         'ay' : ['ao' , 'ih'],
         'ow' : ['o' , 'aa'],
         'oy' : ['o' , 'ih']
        }   

print "Usage :python co.py phonemeFile"

def coart(phonemeFile):
""" Function for generating parameter values from the global list """
phonemeList = []
with open("syllabifiedPhonemes.txt", "r") as pFile :
    for line in pFile :
        l = line.split()
        for phoneme in l : 
            next_phoneme = diphthong.get(phoneme)
            if next_phoneme is None :
                # exploring the dict param_values extracting each nested dict
                for group in param_values.keys() : # 'group' refers to vowels or consonants
                    # iterate over each nested dict 
                    for phones in param_values[group].keys() : # 'phones' refers to the phonemes present inside each group 
                        phonemeList.append((phones, param_values.get(param_values[group][phones])))
            else : 
                for group in param_values.keys() : # 'group' refers to vowels or consonants
                    for phones in param_values[group].keys() : # 'phones' refers to the phonemes present inside each group 
                        phonemeList.extend([(phones, param_values.get(param_values[group][phones])) for phoneme in next_phoneme])

        print "New List"
        print '\n'.join(str(l) for l in phonemeList)
```

The input file syllabifiedPhonemes.txt has the following contents:

```
s aa ' m ih ' k l eh k ' t aa ' n ih t ' g eh l ' v ae ' n ih ' k aa ' p l ay k
```

The if-else statement is not right as far as I can see. I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "co.py", line 189, in <module>
coart("syllabifiedPhonemes.txt")
  File "co.py", line 160, in coart
phonemeList.append((phones, param_values.get(param_values[group][phones])))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I changed the if-else statement to the following and got rid of the error.

```
if next_phoneme is None :
    # exploring the dict param_values extracting each nested dict
    for group in param_values.keys() : # 'group' refers to vowels or consonants
        # iterate over each nested dict 
        for phones in param_values[group].keys() : # 'phones' refers to the phonemes present inside each group 
            phonemeList.append((phones, param_values[group][phones]))
else : 
    for group in param_values.keys() : # 'group' refers to vowels or consonants
        for phones in param_values[group].keys() : # 'phones' refers to the phonemes present inside each group 
            phonemeList.extend([(phones, param_values[group][phones]) for phoneme in next_phoneme])
```

But now I got the output as a huge list and I presume the program iterates through the dict many times and prints the whole dict again and again instead of just displaying the values of the given input. Could someone point out where I am wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to use a nested dictionary here. Removing the layer with Vowels and consonants would simplify this significently

Comment: @james I have to use the nested dictionary because I have to do much more after I have the list of input phonemes with their values mostly comparing the values(ranges) between each other. And their I have different conditions / rules for a phoneme being a consonant or a vowel.

Comment: but by putting them in a list here you lose that information it would be much simpler to put that into a separate data structure and retrieve it later. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. It is much simpler and much more efficient (I think)

```
import sys

param_values = {
            'aa' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),   (-1,-1)],     
            'ae' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (0.1,0.8), (-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ah' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ao' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.2,1.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'eh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'er' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.15,0.7),  (-1,-1)], 
            'ey' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (0.3,1.0), (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.5),   (-1,-1)],
            'ih' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'iy' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (0.2,1.0), (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'uh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (0.1,1.0)], 
            'uw' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (0.1,1.0)],   
            'o'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (0.4,1.0)] ,   
            'b'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.0,0.0),  (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ch' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'd'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'dh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.35),  (-1,-1)], 
            'dx' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.35),  (-1,-1)], 
            'f'  : [(0.3,1.0), (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (-1,-1)], 
            'g'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'hh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'jh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'k'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'l'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'm'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.0,0.0),  (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'n'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (0.3,1.0), (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'ng' : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'p'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.0,0.0),  (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.8),   (-1,-1)], 
            'r'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            's'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (0.3,1.0), (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)],
            'sh' : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (0.3,1.0), (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            't'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'th' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.4),   (-1,-1)], 
            'v'  : [(0.3,1.0), (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (-1,-1)], 
            'w'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),     (0.1,1.0)], 
            'y'  : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.6),   (-1,-1)],  
            'z'  : [(-1,-1),   (0.1,1.0),  (-1,-1),   (0.3,1.0), (0.0,0.0),   (-1,-1)], 
            'zh' : [(-1,-1),   (-1,-1),    (-1,-1),   (-1,-1),   (0.1,0.6),   (-1,-1)]                         
            }

diphthong = { 
         'aw' : ['ao' , 'uw'],
         'ay' : ['ao' , 'ih'],
         'ow' : ['o' , 'aa'],
         'oy' : ['o' , 'ih']
        }   


phonemeList = []
with open("syllabifiedPhonemes.txt", "r") as pFile :
    for line in pFile :
        l = line.split()
        for phoneme in l : 
            if phoneme != "'":
                next_phoneme = diphthong.get(phoneme)
                if next_phoneme is None :
                    # exploring the dict param_values extracting each nested dict
                    phonemeList.append((phoneme, param_values[phoneme]))
                else : 
                    phonemeList.extend([(phoneme, param_values[phoneme]) for phoneme in next_phoneme])

        print "New List"
        print '\n'.join(str(l) for l in phonemeList)
```

If you need the consonant/vowel information it is better storing it somewhere else. Storing it here complicates the code too much.

NOTE: I took out the function for testing purposes. Obviously you should put this back in your code ;)

Comment: I started with the same code then when I had to separate them as vowels and consonants then I added a new layer to the dict. I understand this is much simpler. Like you said storing vowels and consonants separately would be a better idea. Can that be done in a file and access the file to see if a phoneme is a vowel or consonant before updating further?

Comment: Why use a file? Just add another dictionary where your key is the phoneme and the value is vowel or consonant

Comment: Because I already have a file where there are the same phonemes separated into vowels, consonants, onsets etc. That file is utilized by my other program to syllabify the input and thats how I get those apostrophes in the input file which you can see in my question. So I can open the same file again in this program again I guess.

Answer (score 1):

`param_values.get` should not be used there, since you already used `param_values[...]` to read the value.

i.e. instead of:

```
param_values.get(param_values[group][phones])
```

Use:

```
param_values[group][phones]
```

You can use `get` instead of (not in addition to) `[...]` if you want a default value in case the key doesn't exist, but in this case that isn't necessary.

Comment: I forgot to add the input in my question so just edited it. Doing what you suggested I got rid of the error but I didn't get the desired output. The output was like a massive list. I think the program iterated over the list again and again then displayed the whole dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you're doing:

```
param_values.get(param_values['vowels']['aa'])
```

But the problem is that

```
param_values['vowels']['aa']
```

returns a list and you're trying to get a value in the map using a list, which is unhashable and you can't use it as key in the map.

I believe that what you trying to do is just get what

```
param_values['vowels']['aa']
```

returns

Try that in the python console and you will find out the error.

Check this out:

```
What can be a dictionary key? 

Strings can be dictionary keys: 

mydict = {"dog":"Hund", "rhinoceros":"Nashorn"} 

Integers can be dictionary keys. The following dictionary (somewhat redundantly) 
maps prime numbers to their rank, e.g. 2 is the first prime number. 

prime_nums = {2:1, 3:2, 5:3, 7:4, 11:5} 

Floating point numbers can be dictionary keys as well: 
>>> mydict = {3.1415 : "pi", 2.71828 : "e" } 
>>> mydict[3.1415] 
'pi’ 

Lists cannot be dictionary keys
>>> mydict = {[1,2] : "wont_work"} 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
 TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

[More info](http://comp.ling.utexas.edu/_media/courses/2009/spring/working_with_corpora/python_dictionaries.pdf)

---

Ok, first of all, try iterating over the dict using the following code

```
for k, v in dict.items():
    # k is the key
    # v is the value
    pass
```

It will make your code cleaner and maybe it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, yes I got rid of the error by just doing that. Now I have a different issue. I will edit the question.

Comment: I will try this. Does the k here refers to the nested dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

This is in reply to your current new code version snippet below:

```
if next_phoneme is None :
    # exploring the dict param_values extracting each nested dict
    for group in param_values.keys() : # 'group' refers to vowels or consonants
        # iterate over each nested dict 
        for phones in param_values[group].keys() : # 'phones' refers to the phonemes present inside each group 
            phonemeList.append((phones, param_values[group][phones]))
else : 
    for group in param_values.keys() : # 'group' refers to vowels or consonants
        for phones in param_values[group].keys() : # 'phones' refers to the phonemes present inside each group 
            phonemeList.extend([(phones, param_values[group][phones]) for phoneme in next_phoneme])
```

If I understand correctly the goal, I think what you want can be written as:

```
next_phonemes = diphthong.get(phoneme, [phoneme])
for next_phoneme in next_phonemes:
    # exploring the dict param_values extracting each nested dict
    for group_val in param_values.itervalues(): # 'group_val' refers to values associated to vowels or consonants
        if next_phoneme in group_val:
            phonemeList.append((next_phoneme, group_val[next_phoneme])
            break # Once we found the next phoneme, no need to look further
```

Comment: Note that it would be more efficient, as pointed out by jamesj (but I can't comment in his answer), to use a 'flattened' dictionary. You can do this with: `flat_params = params_values['vowels'].copy(); flat_params.update(params_values['consonants'])`. Then you could replace the whole loop in my code by `phonemeList += [(next_phoneme, flat_params[next_phoneme]) for next_phoneme in next_phonemes]`

Comment: To create the list initially, I don't need to know which is vowel and which is consonant.It just needs the corresponding values form the global list. I need to make sure which group a phoneme falls further in the code. So I would do change the dict back to how it was and use the file which I already have where there phonemes are separated into vowels and consonants.